MATLAB Optimisation where the user must return the value of the objective function
Here is the context :
A function has 3 variables. All are positive integers ranging from 0 to 100. The value of all variables are passed to a human that operate of processing equipment and a result is obtained. The result is also an integer ranging from 0 to 100, where 100 is the value to obtain.
Is it possible to have a MATLAB script using optimisation algorithm (simplex, linear descend etc.) where:

Initial values set by the operator are added as initial optimisation variable in a csv file (file1.csv)
Result are stored in a different csv file (file2.csv)
The optimisation algorithm propose new parameter values and append file1.csv
The next result from the operator are appended in file2.csv
Step 3 and 4 are repeated until a value of 98 and above is reached.

I have worked with optimisation, but never where the user has to input the value of the objective function or blackbox.

Interesting open-loop problem. You could try something like below, where you pause inside the objective function until the operator has uploaded the data
% read initial values from file1.csv into x_Initial
x = fmincon(@func_obj, x_Initial)
function f = func_obj(x)
   % append x to file1.csv
   pause();
   % read f from file2.csv
end

